# Image getting distorted on scaling with glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

i am using glide to load image into image view in recyclerview
but for low resolution phone image is getting distorted where as same image when opened in a browser is visible correctly

it works correctly in high end phones

following is my code below

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).apply(requestOptions).
            into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Drawable drawable, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                    BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
                    int width = bd.getBitmap().getWidth();
                    int height = bd.getBitmap().getHeight();
                    int phoneWidth = PhoneUtils.getScreenWidth(context);
                    float phW = phoneWidth;
                    float wid = width;
                    float factor = phW / wid;
                    double h = factor * height;
                    height = (int) Math.ceil(h);
                    width = phoneWidth;
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bd.getBitmap(), width, height, false);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            });
```

the distortion happens slightly in text which is written

is there some problem in scaling the image?

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
@Override
public void onResourceReady(Drawable drawable, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
            BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
            int phoneWidth = PhoneUtils.getScreenWidth(context);
            float phW = phoneWidth;
            float wid = width;
            float factor = phW / wid;
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postScale(factor, factor);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bd.getBitmap(), 0, 0,
                    width, height, matrix, true);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 }
```

using matrix to resize.